# scrollViewDidScroll method not giving reference to all scrollviews from table view

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have created tableView with custom cells that contain image view and scrollView. All scroll views contain labels wider than screen bounds, so when I scroll to left/right I want all scrollViews to scroll in same direction. Problem is I don't know how to get reference to each scrollView in scrollViewDidScroll method.

my viewController class:

```
#import "EPGViewController.h"

@interface EPGViewController (){
    NSArray *EPGList;
    int scrollPositionX;
}

@end

@implementation EPGViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = false;

    EPGList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12", nil];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return EPGList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *hlCellID = @"EPGCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:hlCellID];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc]
               initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:hlCellID];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:15];
    label.text = EPGList[indexPath.row];

    UIScrollView *scrolView = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:16];
    scrolView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    scrolView.delegate = self;
    scrolView.tag = indexPath.row+101;
    scrolView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrolView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrolView.frame.size.width,scrolView.frame.size.height);
    [scrolView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrolView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<15;i++){
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0+i*100, 0, 100, 100)];
        label.text = @"HELLO";
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18];
        [scrolView addSubview:label];
        scrolView.contentSize =    CGSizeMake(scrolView.frame.size.width+i*label.frame.size.width,scrolView.frame.size.height);
    }
    [cell addSubview:scrolView];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 80.0;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)callerScrollView {
    scrollPositionX = callerScrollView.contentOffset.x;

    //if this is called with table view exit
    if (callerScrollView == self.tableView) return;

    int indexPath = callerScrollView.tag-101;
    NSLog(@"TAG: %d",indexPath);

    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        //TODO: Don’t use tags.
        UIScrollView *cellScrollView = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:16];
        if (callerScrollView == cellScrollView) continue;

        cellScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollPositionX, 0);
    }
}


@end
```

**EDIT:**

I managed to solve my problem by deleting line where I add different tags to scrollviews in table view. now I just set offset to scrollview with tag 16.

Comment: In which class are you defining scrollViewDidScroll?

Comment: In viewController that controls table view. UIScrollViewDelegate is included in .h file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple wrong things in your code. Here is better implementation:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)callerScrollView {
    scrollPositionX = callerScrollView.contentOffset.x;

    if (callerScrollView == self.tableView) return;

    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {

        //TODO: Don’t use tags.
        UIScrollView *cellScrollView = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:16];
        if (callerScrollView == cellScrollView) continue;

        cellScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollPositionX, 0);
    }
}
```

Some additonal notes:

- This method will be called by table view too, so you will have to check that.
- Don’t use any indexes, just plain iteration.
- I used checking of scrollViews, but basically there it would be OK without it.
- Using tags to identify subviews is not a good idea.
- **Don’t call `reloadData` every time!**

Comment: I have for example lets say 10 elements in table view array, so I added 10 different tags for scrollViews in table cell. How can I access those 10 cells without tag? I have to update contentOffset just on cells that I am not dragging (9 of them). How can I recognize them without tag?

Comment: So you have 10 cells, each with one scrollView? You can update the contentOffset on all 10 scrollViews, it has no effect on the one you are dragging. You would set `x` to `x`. Then it’s usual, that you subclass the `UITableViewCell` and create properties to access inner views. Or even better, you create just the methods `-updateXOffsetTo:` for example.

Comment: I found my error! I don't need to add another tag to each scrollview, it is enough just to set tag 16 and now it all works!

Comment: Problem with visibleCells is that when i scroll down my list, other cells are not as I need them to be, and correct cells are reseted at beginning of scroll view. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may be reseting them in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should be familiar with cell-reusing. In your tableView, there are only few cell alive at any time and they remain the same ones. If you want to affect **all** cells, you need to affect visible ones and those created in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I saw my problem now but didn't find solution yet. Problem is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` uses 0 and not `scrollPositionX` value for third cell that needs to be displayed. (for 2 cells that I scroll it displays offset with correct `scrollPositionX`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [tableView visibleCells]; in order to get all cells that are visible at this moment.

Comment: I tried that, but array of visibleCells is returning me nil. See my edit.

Comment: [self.tableView visibleCells]; is returning nil? can you upload your code on git I'm a little curious about this.

Comment: I added whole .m file with suggestions that iMartin gave me.

Comment: No, scrollViews aren't updating.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **UITableView**'s *visibleCells* method to get all visible cells and get your scrollviews from there (you can use *viewwithTag* like you do, but on all cells).

Then you would have to remember to adjust the scrollview position as cells are reused/recreated - probably keep the scrolled offset as a property of your View Controller.

Comment: I edited my post with your suggestion, but still I don't get movement on other cells. Am I doing something wrong again?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier rather than just looping through the cells that have already been displayed.

Do something like:

```
for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
{
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
    {
       if (!(indexPath.section == j && indexPath.row == i))
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]]]; 
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:16]; 
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(position_x, scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Or loop through the array you get from [tableView visibleCells] as suggested in the other answers. Whatever you do, don't dequeue!

Comment: I have tried this, but other cells are not updating. After this code you suggested I just added `[self.tableView reloadData];`